# How to decide what to mention in .spec file 'Requires: ' filed

Tags: rpm, dependencies, rpmbuild

I am new in building rpm package.For Creating RPM for my binary I have following dependancies:

```
[tejas@target]$ ldd exe
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff85bff000)
    libQtWebKit.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0x00007f868c4e8000)
    libphonon.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libphonon.so.4 (0x00007f868c288000)
    libQtScript.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtScript.so.4 (0x00007f868bdd3000)
    libQt3Support.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQt3Support.so.4 (0x00007f868b8b5000)
    libQtSql.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtSql.so.4 (0x00007f868b66f000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f868b426000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f868a6c7000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f868a369000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f8689e72000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003cd2200000)
    libqwt.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libqwt.so.6 (0x00007f8689b4e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003cd8200000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003cd1a00000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003cd7e00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003cd1600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003cd1e00000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x000000373ba00000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00000030aa000000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f2e00000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f0e00000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f1a00000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f2200000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f1e00000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00000034f1600000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00000030b1200000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00000030a9800000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x0000003cdba00000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00000030b4400000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003cd2a00000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00000030b0e00000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x0000003cd5e00000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x0000003cd5a00000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x000000373b600000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x0000003e83600000)
    libQtDBus.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtDBus.so.4 (0x00007f86898c1000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 (0x0000003cd5600000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003cd2600000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x000000373d200000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x0000003cdb200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003cd1200000)
    libQtSvg.so.4 => /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f8689662000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003cd3600000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003cd2e00000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x0000003cd5200000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x0000003e82600000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x0000003e83200000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x0000003e81e00000)
```

So I have checked from which rpm I can get those libraries by `rpm -qf <library path>` command.
eg:

```
[tejas@target]$ rpm -qf /lib64/libpthread.so.0
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
```

I have also checked which minimum version should be available for that library. So, accordingly I made spec file including all those packges.

My .spec file is:

```
[tejas@target]$ cat /home/tejas/rpmbuild/SPECS/ModCMS-gdm.spec
Name:   ModCMS-gdm  
Version:1.0 
Release:1
Summary:gdm     

Group:  ModCMS  
License:WESEE   
URL:    http://wesee.org    
Source0:ModCMS-gdm-1.0.tar.gz   

Requires:dbus-libs >= 1.2.24
Requires:expat >= 2.0.1
Requires:fontconfig >= 2.8.0
Requires:freetype >= 2.3.11
Requires:glib2 >= 2.22.5
Requires:glibc >= 2.12
Requires:keyutils-libs >= 1.4
Requires:krb5-libs >= 1.8.2
Requires:libasyncns >= 0.8
Requires:libcom_err >= 1.41.12
Requires:libgcc >= 4.4.4
Requires:libICE >= 1.0.6
Requires:libpng >= 1.2.44
Requires:libqwt6 = 6.0.1
Requires:libselinux >= 2.0.94
Requires:libSM >= 1.1.0
Requires:libsndfile >= 1.0.20
Requires:libstdc++ >= 4.4.4
Requires:libuuid >= 2.17.2
Requires:libXau >= 1.0.5
Requires:libxcb >= 1.5
Requires:libXcursor >= 1.1.10
Requires:libXext >= 1.1
Requires:libXfixes >= 4.0.4
Requires:libXi >= 1.3
Requires:libXinerama >= 1.1
Requires:libXrandr >= 1.3.0
Requires:libXrender >= 0.9.5
Requires:libXtst >= 1.0.99.2
Requires:openssl >= 1.0.1e
Requires:pulseaudio-libs >= 0.9.21
Requires:qt48 >= 4.8.5
Requires:qt48-x11 >= 4.8.5
Requires:qtwebkit >= 2.0
Requires:sqlite >= 3.6.20
Requires:tcp_wrappers-libs >= 7.6
Requires:zlib >= 1.2.3


%description
This is Just to test various files allocation through rpm build

%prep
%setup -q

%install
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/root/ModCMS"
cp -r GDM.tar.gz "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/root/ModCMS/"

%files
/root/ModCMS/GDM.tar.gz

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post
cd /root/ModCMS/
tar xzf GDM.tar.gz
```

Now my questions are :

- How do I mansion dependency libraries directly instead of rpm?
- Is it necessary to include all those dependencies in Required field?
- How do I minimize them?

I have searched, but couldn't find specific solution.

Comment: `rpm` should do it automatically based on `ldd` output. See http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies#AutomaticDependencies

Comment: but my RPM package contains compressed zip files which also contains my binary, I just need to extract that zip file in particular location.

Comment: Why do they need to be inside a zip file?  Things will be easier without it.

Comment: because there are more than 800 files which ,I guess!, I need to specify in `.spec` files `%files` field.

Comment: `%files` takes an `-f filename` option.  Or you could generate the `%files` block based on `unzip -l` or `tar -t` output.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you are building for a specific distribution, depending on other rpms is ok.

If building for different distributions, rather use library/file names, as the rpm-names where that lib is contained might differ.

Comment: no I need to build for my current distribution only.

Comment: @Tejas so go for rpms. That way your spec should survive all minor and some major release updates.